# Problem with Intent that takes and ID from Firebase Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-intent

I have a problem with the Intent from a class that sends an extra string with Course_ID as you can see in the Firebase Database image. Sometimes in class UploadFile.class, the String that get the intent with extra string (that contains Course_ID), gets a null value. If you can recommend me a new method to apply for getting this Course_ID from Firebase, I will be thankful. Below this text are attached the screen of Firebase Database, the error that I get sometimes in UploadFile.class and also the code for UploadFile.class and a part of my code from the class that sends this intent with extra string.

UploadFile.class

```
public class UploadFile extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText denumire_material;
    Button selectare_material;
    ImageView adaugare_material;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    FirebaseAuth mFirebaseAuth;
    FirebaseDatabase reference;
    private FirebaseStorage storage;
    private StorageReference storageReference;
    private Uri pdfUri;
    String url;
    String generatedFilePath;
    Uri downloadUri;
    TeacherCoursesFragment teacherCoursesFragment = new TeacherCoursesFragment();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_upload_file);

        denumire_material = findViewById(R.id.editBoxDenumireMaterial);
        selectare_material = findViewById(R.id.btnSelectareMaterial);
        adaugare_material = findViewById(R.id.imgAddMaterial);
        mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();


        storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
        reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Materials").child(mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());

        selectare_material.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(UploadFile.this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    selectPDF();
                } else{
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(UploadFile.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},9);

                }
            }
        });

        adaugare_material.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(pdfUri!=null){
                    uploadFile(pdfUri);
                    adaugareDateInFirebase();
                } else{}
            }
        });
    }

        private void adaugareDateInFirebase(){
            DatabaseReference reference1 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
            Query query = reference1.child(mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
                    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
                    Date date = new Date();
                    String datee = dateFormat.format(date).toString();
                    String course_id = getIntent().getExtras().getString("course id").toString();
                    HashMap<String, Object> firebase = new HashMap<>();
                    firebase.put("Denumire_material", denumire_material.getText().toString());
                    firebase.put("Locatie_material", generatedFilePath);
                    firebase.put("Teacher_ID", mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
                    firebase.put("Course_ID", course_id);
                    firebase.put("Data_adaugarii", datee);
                    databaseReference.push().setValue(firebase).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                            if(task.isSuccessful()){

                            }
                        }
                    });
                }

        private void uploadFile(Uri pdfUri) {
        final String fileName = System.currentTimeMillis()+"";
        StorageReference storageReference = storage.getInstance().getReference();

        final StorageReference storageReference1 = storageReference.child("Materiale/" + mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()+"/"+denumire_material.getText().toString());

        storageReference1.putFile(pdfUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
                        generatedFilePath = task.getResult().toString();
                    }
                });
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(UploadFile.this, "File not succesfully uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }).addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onProgress(@NonNull UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if(requestCode == 9 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            selectPDF();
        } else{
            Toast.makeText(UploadFile.this, "Permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }
    }
```

TeacherCoursesFragments.class - the class from where I send the intent with extra string attached (it contains the id of course).

```
public class TeacherCoursesFragment extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    v =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_teacher_courses, container, false);
    ImageView addCourseBtn = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.btnAddCourse);

    recyclerView = v.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView_fragmentCourses);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    String uid = user.getUid();
    createCourse = new CreateCourse();

    reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Courses").child("Teacher-Courses").child(uid);

    intent = new Intent(getActivity(), CreateCourse.class);
    addCourseBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });


    return v;
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Course>().setQuery(reference, Course.class).build();
    adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Course, CourseViewHolder>(options) {
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final CourseViewHolder courseViewHolder, int i, @NonNull final Course course) {
            courseViewHolder.courseRealName.setText(course.getCourse_name());
            String numberOfStudents = String.valueOf(course.getCourse_students());
            courseViewHolder.realNumberOfStudents.setText(numberOfStudents);
            courseViewHolder.detailsButtonCourse2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), CourseMaterial.class);
                    intent.putExtra("course id", course.getCourse_ID());
                    intent.putExtra("teacher id", course.getTeacher_ID());
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

            courseViewHolder.course_chenar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), CourseOperations.class);
                    intent.putExtra("course name", course.getCourse_name());
                    intent.putExtra("course description", course.getCourse_description());
                    intent.putExtra("course points", String.valueOf(course.getCourse_points()));
                    intent.putExtra("course students", String.valueOf(course.getCourse_students()));
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

            courseViewHolder.detailsButtonCourse.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), UploadFile.class);
                    intent.putExtra("course id", course.getCourse_ID());
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

        }
```

Am I supposed to make 2 DatabaseReference, one for Teacher-Courses and one for Materials? I've tried that but I can't get the Course_ID from Teacher-Courses without an Intent. I've searched on stackoverflow and on the Google but I haven't found any solution at all. Waiting for responses, advices or solutions from you, if you can give me some. Thank you!

The additional explanation: The name of the course and also the number of students (second title) are extracted from Firebase Database using the RecyclerViewAdapter and RecyclerViewOptions as you can see in TeacherCoursesFragment.class. The first button redirects to UploadFile.class where I upload a file and establish a name for it to be stored in Firebase Storage. The second button sends the user to another page where user can select from multiple options (delete, etc.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Maybe change this in `UploadFile`:**

```
String course_id = getIntent().getExtras().getString("course id").toString();
```

**To this:**

```
String course_id = getIntent().getStringExtra("course id");
```

**Update:**

I guess you should be calling `getIntent()` in `onCreate()`:

**In your `UploadFile`**

```
public class UploadFile extends AppCompatActivity {

........
//declare as member variable
private String course_id;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.fragment_upload_file);

//get it here
course_id = getIntent().getStringExtra("course id");
.......
.......
.......

}




}
```

**Remove this line that you are using:**

```
String course_id = getIntent().getExtras().getString("course id").toString();
```

Comment: I'm still getting the error. I will attach the rest of code from TeacherCoursesFragment.class, because I think will be usefull to see the full view of transaction between these classes.

Comment: Also, I will add extra explanation in this comment. I have 2 buttons in my screen - one that redirect to a page where I upload Files to Firebase Storage and one Image (that acts as a button) that redirects me to a page where I have multiple options - to remove a course, to add materials (as I said earlier with Firebase Storage). And this intent with extra string is from TeacherCourseFragment.class. The class UploadFile.class and the class that has the multiple options for courses has the same intent sent from TeacherCoursesFragment.class.

Comment: No. I get it first in TeacherCoursesFragments.class from FirebaseDatabase. I am attaching a new image to this post to be more precise and I will add a new explanation between as a P.S.

Comment: I have uploaded additional explanations. I feel so bad that I haven't posted them from the first time. Sorry.

Comment: Show me this class `Course `.

Comment: Done! I have modified the post and added Course.class and another class that I have used in UploadFile.class

Comment: When you click the details button, instead of going to next activity, Log the value to the console of `course_id` and see if it is null or not.

Comment: When I press the detailsButtonCourse from TeacherCoursesFragment.class that redirects me to another activity with multiple operations to be applied to the course. One of them are Adding materials on Firebase Storage. When I press the button for materials, it gets null.

Comment: Great if this helped accept the answer so others with same problem know that this is a solution.